# jquery progressbar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

anyone know any sample of a jquery progressbar for a asp.net mvc 2 web application?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Reload Progress Bar](http://codecanyon.net/item/reloadprogressbar-jquery-plugin/5392218) and it works really nice. It's not free though.